# non-nullable variable is not initialized

Tags: flutter, dart

I am having this problem where it says the non nuablle variable must be initialized

[image]

```
  static MediaQueryData _mediaQueryData;
  static double screenWidth;
  static double screenHeight;
  static double deafualtSize;
  static Orientation orientation;

  void init(BuildContext context) {
    _mediaQueryData = MediaQuery.of(context);
    screenWidth = _mediaQueryData.size.width;
    screenHeight = _mediaQueryData.size.height;
    orientation = _mediaQueryData.orientation;
  }
}
```

Comment: The error you are facing is not in the code you shows. You have a non nullablle parameter somewhere (with attribute @required).

Comment: This is weird as I still have not used them anywhere and it already shows the error

Comment: Can you post your stacktrace. You can add that after your question..

Comment: I have added it

Comment: Can you post the class those are inside? THe code you have posted is to small to unddertand

Comment: Sorry for not showing much deatails I am still a beginner, however it has been solved thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ig you need to do something like this

```
 static MediaQueryData _mediaQueryData = 0;
  static double screenWidth = 0;
  static double screenHeight = 0;
  static double deafualtSize = 0;
  static Orientation? orientation;
  
  void init(BuildContext context) {
    _mediaQueryData = MediaQuery.of(context);
    screenWidth = _mediaQueryData.size.width;
    screenHeight = _mediaQueryData.size.height;
    orientation = _mediaQueryData.orientation;
  }
}
```

Everythime you use the orientation variable you will have to call it like orientation!
This error is because of the new null safety feature. You have to either give a default value or say that the variable can be null by using a ? after the type declaration as in the example above
Hope it helps. Let me know if there is any other problem